# Integral of Coulomb interaction over sphere

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics, electromagnetism

I am stuck evaluating an integral that appears in a simplified theory of nuclear binding energy. The nucleus is modelled as a sphere of radius $R$ with a continuous charge distribution, and the integral gives the force experienced by a new proton of radius $r_0$. Here's the geometry:

[geometry of nucleus-proton Coulomb interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m9B4.jpg)

The force along the line joining the proton-nucleus centers is
$$
F = \frac{3e^2}{32\pi^2\epsilon_0r_0^3}\int \frac{\cos\alpha}{d^2}d\boldsymbol{r}
$$

I approached this by using the cosine rule for $\cos\alpha = (r^2 - R'^2 - d^2)/(2R'd)$ and $d=r^2+R'^2 - 2rR'\cos\theta$ but I can't do the resulting integral, which i think is
$$
2\pi \int_0^\pi \int_0^R \frac{(r\cos\theta-R')r^2\sin\theta}{(r^2 + R'^2 - 2rR'\cos\theta)^{5/2}}\,\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
This integral leads me down a mess of algebra in $r$ if I try to substitute $u=\cos\theta$. Can anyone provide some hints or correct my working?

EDIT: I tried $u^2 = r^2 + R'^2 - 2rR'\cos\theta$ and got the $\theta$ integral out to:
$$
\frac{r}{2R'^2}\left[ \frac{1}{u} - \frac{r^2-R'^2}{3u^3} \right]_{R'-r}^{R'+r}
$$
but I'm really struggling to put this function of $r$ into a tidy form I can integrate.

Comment: As a check on future work: Using Mathematica, the integral over $\theta$ (under the assumption that $R<R'$) yields $\frac{2r^2}{3R'^2}\frac{r^2-3R'^2}{(r^2-R'^2)^2}$. The resulting integral over $r$ is readily integrated via Mathematica as well.

Comment: When the new particle is outside the nucleus is there some reason you can't use qE for the force? The electric field of a sphere is well known

Comment: There is a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) due to Newton that might be of interest to you...